# Cannot store multiple arrays in redux state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I want to store multiple arrays in my redux store but following code is not working.

reducer:

```
export interface OrderState {
    fetching: boolean;
    orders: Order[];
    error: string;
    executions: DataModel[];  <===
}
```

When I change executions to be a single object then there is no error:

```
export interface OrderState {
    fetching: boolean;
    orders: Order[];
    error: string;
    executions: DataModel;    <===
}
```

Could anybody please tell me how to maintain multiple arrays in redux reducer?

Error was

> TypeScript error in `src/data/store.ts(14,9)`:
>
> Argument of type '`Partial<State> | undefined`' is not assignable to
> parameter of type
>
> ```
> { orderbooks?: { fetching: boolean; orderbooks:
> any; error: string; orderId: string; totalExecutions: string; } | {
> fetching: boolean; error: any; orderbooks: never[]; orderId: string;
> totalExecutions: string; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | undefined; orders?:
> { ...; } | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } | undefined'.   Type
> 'Partial<State>' is not assignable to type '{ orderbooks?: { fetching:
> boolean; orderbooks: any; error: string; orderId: string;
> totalExecutions: string; } | { fetching: boolean; error: any;
> orderbooks: never[]; orderId: string; totalExecutions: string; } | {
> ...; } | { ...; } | undefined; orders?: { ...; } | ... 2 more ... |
> undefined; }
> ```
>
> - Types of property 'orders' are incompatible.
>   Type 'OrderState | undefined' is not assignable to type
>
> ```
> { fetching: boolean; orders: any; error: string; executions: never[]; }
> | { fetching: boolean; error: any; orders: never[]; executions:
> never[]; } | { fetching: boolean; executions: any; error: string;
> orders: never[]; } | undefined'.
>         Type 'OrderState' is not assignable to type '{ fetching: boolean; orders: any; error: string; executions: never[]; } | {
> fetching: boolean; error: any; orders: never[]; executions: never[]; }
> | { fetching: boolean; executions: any; error: string; orders:
> never[]; } | undefined'.
>           Type 'OrderState' is not assignable to type '{ fetching: boolean; executions: any; error: string; orders: never[]; }'.
>             Types of property 'orders' are incompatible.
>               Type 'LimitOrder[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
>                 Type 'LimitOrder' is not assignable to type 'never'.  TS2345
> ```

```
     12 |     const store = createStore(
     13 |         rootReducer,
   > 14 |         initialState,
        |         ^
     15 |         composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
     16 |     );
     17 |     sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga, services);
```

Initial state:

```
export const initialState = {
    fetching: false,
    orders: [],
    error: "",
    executions: [],
}
```

Comment: Tip: Because Redux state has to be immutable, you should annotate properties with `readonly` **and** annotate member arrays as `readonly T[]` - which helps prevent accidental state mutations. e.g. `export interface OrderState { readonly orders: readonly Order[]; /* etc */ }`

Comment: Please post your `initialState` value. I think you have the wrong type annotation for`executions` in your `initialState`.

Comment: Thanks and I have updated accordingly

Comment: Please post the definition of `DataModel`.

Comment: Also, consider calling `createStore` with explicit type arguments. I think it's inferring the wrong type arguments from your `rootReducer` function, which will make it complain about your `initialState`.

Comment: In your initialState try to use `orders: [] as Order[]` and `executions: [] as DataModel[]`. Also how does your reducer look like?

Comment: Thanks @Rikin, could you please post your comment below so that I can mark it as correct answer?

Comment: @LLD glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initialState try to use `orders: [] as Order[]` and `executions: [] as DataModel[]`.